# How to find $\lim\limits_ {n\to\infty}n^5\int_n^{n+2}\frac{{x}^2}{{ {2+x^7}}}\ dx$?

Tags: integration

How to find $$\displaystyle\lim_ {n\to\infty}n^5\int_n^{n+2}\dfrac{{x}^2}{{ {2+x^7}}}\ dx$$Can I use Mean Value Theorem? Someone suggested I should use Lagrange but I don't know how it would help.

Comment: @Ghartal Or not.

Comment: Hint: 1. You are not asked to compute each integral but only the limit in your post. 2. What is the limit of $$n^5\frac{x^2}{2+x^7}$$ when $n\to\infty$, for every $x$ in $(n,n+2)$?

Comment: No `\displaystyle` in titles, please.

Comment: @Ghartal 50 what? The limit is 50, you think?

Comment: Well I don't know how to proceed in this kind of problems.Do I take the average value of x from the integral (n,n+2) and just replace it in the function?I know my replies are kind of silly but I can't understand how it works

Comment: Hint (cont'ed): 3. For every $x$ in $(n,n+2)$, $$\left(1+\frac2n\right)^{-7}=\frac{n^5\,n^2}{(n+2)^7}\leqslant\frac{n^5x^2}{2+x^7}\leqslant\frac{n^5(n+2)^2}{n^7}=\left(1+\frac2n\right)^2$$ Thus, ...

Comment: You integrate something very close to $\frac{1}{n^5}$ over an interval with length $2$, then multiply such integral by $n^5$. Isn't pretty obvious that the limit is going to be $2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
2n^5\frac{n^2}{2+(n+2)^7}&\le n^5\int_n^{n+2}\frac{x^2}{2+x^7}\,\mathrm{d}x\le2n^5\frac{(n+2)^2}{2+n^7}\\[12pt]
\frac2{\frac2{n^7}+\left(1+\frac2n\right)^7}&\le n^5\int_n^{n+2}\frac{x^2}{2+x^7}\,\mathrm{d}x\le\frac{2\left(1+\frac2n\right)^2}{\frac2{n^7}+1}
\end{align}
$$
Apply the Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^5\int_n^{n+2} \frac{x^2}{x^7+2}\operatorname{dx} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_n^{n+2}\frac{n^7x^2}{n^2(x^7+2)}\operatorname{dx} $$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_n^{n+2} \frac{n^5x^{-5}\operatorname{dx}}{1+2x^{-7}}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_n^{n+2} n^5x^{-5}(1-2x^{-7})\operatorname{dx}$$

Can you do it now?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x^2}{2+x^7}=\frac1{x^5}-\frac 2{x^5(2+x^7)}$$ and

$$\int_n^{n+2}\frac{x^2}{2+x^7}dx=\frac1{4n^4}-\frac1{4(n+2)^4}-\int_n^{n+2}\frac 2{x^5(2+x^7)}dx.$$

The integral on the right is of order $n^{-11}$ and can certainly be neglected.

Then reducing to the common denominator and expanding

$$\frac{n^5}4\frac{(n^4+8n^3+\cdots)-n^4}{n^4(n+2)^4}\to\color{green}2.$$